# line break textview on button clicked not worked

Tags: android, textview, buttonclick

i want to make new line on a textview each time button clicked from input on edittext. But textview only update the first line and not showing multiple lines.
here's what I've done

1) using ordinary line break \r\n

```
enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                resultTextView.setText(inputEditText.getText()+"\r\n");
                inputEditText.setText("");
            }

        });
```

2) using line separator

```
 enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                resultTextView.setText(inputEditText.getText()+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                inputEditText.setText("");
            }

        });
```

Textview's xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dataLogButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:maxLines="20"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

my question is why?why would no line break?
and how do i fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each click, you are replacing the text in 'resultTextView' with what is in 'inputEditText', albeit with a linebreak on the end. You are not adding to what was there before.

I think this is what you are after:

```
resultTextView.setText(resultTextView.getText() + "\r\n" + inputEditText.getText());
```

So you set it to what it currently is, plus a new line break, plus the new line from the edittext.

Comment: thanks man, but how do i skip the line break at the first line? seems like at the first button clicked it initiate a line break.

Comment: Just use an if statement. If resultTextView.getText().equals(""), add without using a line break, otherwise do.